# Why is xtline combining two id variables?

Tags: stata

I have panel data for 16 states for the years 1980 - 2013.

When I run the following command, Stata combines Arkansas and Wisconsin on the key. There are 16 total lines on the graph, but the fact that the two states are combined on the key makes it difficult to edit them and is obviously confusing.

```
xtline hourly_wages, t(Year) i(State) overlay
```

This is my data. I only included a subset because I'm having problems with States Arkansas and Wisconsin. Wisconsin and Arkansas clearly don't have identical hourly_wages trends. Another thing, When I dropped Arkansas from my dataset, the command worked perfectly; each State had its own place on the key.

Thanks for the help.

```
hourly_wages Year State
6.1836538   1980    Arkansas
6.7875      1981    Arkansas
7.1942308   1982    Arkansas
7.6615385   1983    Arkansas
8.0086538   1984    Arkansas
8.2923077   1985    Arkansas
8.6384615   1986    Arkansas
8.8572115   1987    Arkansas
9.0889423   1988    Arkansas
9.3375      1989    Arkansas
9.7211538   1990    Arkansas
10.063942   1991    Arkansas
10.5625     1992    Arkansas
10.759135   1993    Arkansas
11.149519   1994    Arkansas
11.444712   1995    Arkansas
11.927885   1996    Arkansas
12.508654   1997    Arkansas
13.08125    1998    Arkansas
13.602885   1999    Arkansas
14.062019   2000    Arkansas
14.360577   2001    Arkansas
14.792788   2002    Arkansas
15.329808   2003    Arkansas
15.989423   2004    Arkansas
16.447115   2005    Arkansas
16.854808   2006    Arkansas
17.644231   2007    Arkansas
17.943269   2008    Arkansas
17.944712   2009    Arkansas
18.930288   2010    Arkansas
19.476923   2011    Arkansas
20.067308   2012    Arkansas
20.46875    2013    Arkansas
7.6629808   1980    Idaho
8.3701923   1981    Idaho
8.7985577   1982    Idaho
9.2004808   1983    Idaho
9.5168269   1984    Idaho
9.9100962   1985    Idaho
10.229327   1986    Idaho
10.488942   1987    Idaho
10.954808   1988    Idaho
11.393269   1989    Idaho
11.769712   1990    Idaho
12.294712   1991    Idaho
12.900962   1992    Idaho
13.534135   1993    Idaho
14.596154   1994    Idaho
15.621635   1995    Idaho
15.516346   1996    Idaho
16.067788   1997    Idaho
16.450962   1998    Idaho
18.056731   1999    Idaho
21.025481   2000    Idaho
18.126923   2001    Idaho
18.379808   2002    Idaho
18.995673   2003    Idaho
19.970192   2004    Idaho
20.598558   2005    Idaho
21.761058   2006    Idaho
22.246154   2007    Idaho
22.487019   2008    Idaho
22.458173   2009    Idaho
23.744231   2010    Idaho
24.147596   2011    Idaho
24.286058   2012    Idaho
9.3129808   1980    Texas
9.1889423   1981    Texas
9.9245192   1982    Texas
10.374038   1983    Texas
10.820192   1984    Texas
11.385577   1985    Texas
11.779327   1986    Texas
12.225      1987    Texas
12.767788   1988    Texas
13.126442   1989    Texas
13.653365   1990    Texas
14.330769   1991    Texas
15.158173   1992    Texas
15.503846   1993    Texas
15.887019   1994    Texas
16.652404   1995    Texas
17.385577   1996    Texas
18.527885   1997    Texas
19.936538   1998    Texas
20.366827   1999    Texas
21.668269   2000    Texas
22.23125    2001    Texas
22.547115   2002    Texas
23.447596   2003    Texas
24.676923   2004    Texas
26.154808   2005    Texas
27.629808   2006    Texas
28.898558   2007    Texas
29.107212   2008    Texas
29.014904   2009    Texas
30.416346   2010    Texas
31.746154   2011    Texas
32.928365   2012    Texas
33.109615   2013    Texas
8.5394231   1980    Wisconsin
9.3596154   1981    Wisconsin
9.8985577   1982    Wisconsin
10.390385   1983    Wisconsin
10.889423   1984    Wisconsin
11.307212   1985    Wisconsin
11.63125    1986    Wisconsin
11.972115   1987    Wisconsin
12.427885   1988    Wisconsin
12.612981   1989    Wisconsin
13.103846   1990    Wisconsin
13.483654   1991    Wisconsin
14.316346   1992    Wisconsin
14.528846   1993    Wisconsin
15.059615   1994    Wisconsin
15.518269   1995    Wisconsin
16.088462   1996    Wisconsin
17.070192   1997    Wisconsin
17.502885   1998    Wisconsin
18.160096   1999    Wisconsin
19.183173   2000    Wisconsin
18.855769   2001    Wisconsin
19.522115   2002    Wisconsin
20.215385   2003    Wisconsin
21.227404   2004    Wisconsin
21.373558   2005    Wisconsin
22.116827   2006    Wisconsin
22.649038   2007    Wisconsin
23.134135   2008    Wisconsin
22.971635   2009    Wisconsin
24.186058   2010    Wisconsin
24.728365   2011    Wisconsin
25.190385   2012    Wisconsin
25.537019   2013    Wisconsin
```

Comment: Note that the title is misleading. Here there is precisely one identifier variable with several distinct values; what is happening is that by default some of those values are represented in the same way on the graph once the number of distinct values passes 15.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a reproducible example of your problem. Here's one:

```
clear 
set obs 34
set seed 2803
egen state = seq(), block(2)
egen time = seq(), to(2)
xtset state time
gen y = rnormal()
xtline y, overlay
```

The problem for you is that with nothing else said, Stata here cycles over only 15 distinct plot styles, and then starts recycling: see `help pstyle` for a start. But with even 15 styles, the legend takes up about half the graph space. So it's hard to see why this graph is drawn at all, as for real data it will just be a mess squeezed into a small space. If you want more differentiation I think you will need to spell out your own line patterns, colours, etc. Stata will not do that for you. It's the programmer's way of saying "Over to you!".

As you guess, the problem is nothing to do with data for the particular states; the number of panels is the critical fact, regardless of whether their data are similar, different, awkward or well-behaved.

Although we are well away from purely programming issues, I would not use `overlay` for such data.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the suggestions on format and for clearing up my confusion. I agree that with all this information, 16 individual lines on a graph is visually overwhelming.